# Custom field fetch error on woocommerce pdf invoice

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to do some modifications to a template of WooCommerce, but I'm rather ZERO in PHP, so that is why I'm asking some guidance so I could perform my small modifications, which I'm sure are not too difficult.

So I have a plugin which generates me a PDF document from an invoice template, that invoice template is in PHP, so I need an extra field to that template.
There is an error while fetching Custom field of loyal_card.
Check attachment for further.[image]

Comment: <tr class="loyalty_card">
                    <th><?php _e( 'Loyalty Card:', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips' ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php $this->loyalty_card(); ?></td>
                </tr>

Comment: *so I could perform my small modifications, which I'm sure are not too difficult.*. How can you assess if the task is small and not too difficult if you have no experience with PHP, I would assume no experience with WordPress code as well. If you have no experience with modifying code then contact the plugins author or hire a developer. Depending on how the plugin is built you'll need to hook into an action/filter, override a template, or something else completely. Without us having this exact plugin on our install it would be impossible to help using this screenshot alone.